# Simple loop to make a hour counter? MQL4

Tags: mql4, mql5

Im trying to make a counter, simple counter, that add 1 every hour.

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try already? Can you share your current code?

Answer (score 0):

It's a very simple concept. The following code will increase the variable `counter` by one every new hour.

```
static int counter;
static datetime hour;
if(hour!=iTime(NULL, PERIOD_H1,0)) {counter++; hour=iTime(NULL, PERIOD_H1,0);}
```

Comment: If you are happy with the answer @DavidSalem , please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can using Timer:

```
int count = 0;
int OnInit()
{
 EventSetTimer(60); //every 60s
 return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);
}
void OnTimer()
{
  count++;
}
```